# Avoiding redundancy in updating an object's properties

Tags: c#

When I instantiate a new entity, it looks like this:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity() 
{
    Field1 = "myValue",
    Field2 = "myOtherValue",
    ...
}
```

This avoids having to write `myEntity.Field1` many time.

But when I have to update multiple properties, I don't know any way to avoid the repetition of code. So at the moment, I do like this:

```
myEntity.Field1 = "myNewValue";
myEntity.Field2 = "myOtherNewValue";
...
```

Does C# allow any more concise way of updating multiple properties?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even possible to get more concise than what you currently have - let alone if C# has implemented that syntax.

Comment: why don't you create a method as UpdateEntity with fields as parameters and reuse this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [C# with keyword equivalent](http://omaralzabir.com/c__with_keyword_equivalent/). It's a bit sloppy, but it is the closest you can get to the [VB.NET With statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Also take a look at this blog post: [Simple equivalent of “With” statement in C#](http://anaykamat.com/2009/08/09/simple-equivalent-of-with-statement-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 2):

Going on @daryal's comment above, you could create an update method with all of the parameters being optional:

```
public void UpdateEntity(string Field1 = null, string Field2 = null, string Field3 = null) 
{
  this.Field1 = Field1 ?? this.Field1;
  this.Field2 = Field2 ?? this.Field2;
  this.Field3 = Field3 ?? this.Field3;
}
```

Then call it with named parameters:

```
e.UpdateEntity(Field1: "foo", Field3: "fiz");
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but another option. If I were doing stuff like this all of the time, I would probably go with the "C# with keyword equivalent" that @Brian shared.

**Note:** this solution requires C# 4.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. VB.NET has the [With statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but there's no equivalent in C#.