# How can i set more than one property with the use of dot operator and object can use only in first statement

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I set more than one property with the use of dot operator and object is using only in first statement?

```
form.toolStripCollect.Enabled = true,
    .toolStripButton2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You can use :

form.toolStripCollect.Enabled = form.toolStripButton2.Visible = true;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding redundancy in updating an object's properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318308/avoiding-redundancy-in-updating-an-objects-properties)

Comment: You're probably looking for `fluent` design :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic has the [`With...End With`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) statement, which seems to be what you're looking for. This does not exist in c#.

The language *does* support setting properties while constructing the instance:

```
Form f = new Form()
{
    Top = 10,
    Left = 20,
}
```

Like Bob Dust mentioned in the comments, the fluent design also comes close to this. Objects have methods that perform an operation and then return itself:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass SetEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        Enabled = enabled;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This allows you to "chain" method calls:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.SetEnabled(true)
 .SetOtherProperty("hi");
```

Unfortunately you cannot do this with properties the normal way (`Property = value`) and you would have add a bunch of extension methods around existing classes in order to use it.